# How is this plot called?

Tags: data-visualization, markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence

The three plots on the bottom are regular line plots but how are three top subplots called? The picture is taken from p. 45 here: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecbwp769.pdf?9570e6e4c82cc1b22c891b0d412af1bc

[image: Inefficiency_factors]

Comment: Looks like line plots to me, just with a very high frequency, making it look like an area.

Comment: Seem to be [periodograms](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, *all six* of these plots are line plots; they show a measure of the efficiency of the MCMC sampler for different subsets of the parameters. The first four (counting right-to-left, top-to-bottom) represent subsets with much larger numbers of parameters, and in some cases (I guess) some kind of periodicity in the meaning of the parameters (e.g. the $\theta_t$s in the top plot form a time series, and probably have a seasonal component), which makes for an interesting visual appearance - but they're not qualitatively different from the last two.

At least in my experience with general MCMCs, this is not a very widespread graphical convention for assessing MCMC chains - maybe more common in econometrics (e.g. also mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251956/inefficiency-and-convergence-of-mcmc)). It shows the **efficiency** of the MCMC - in my opinion (contradicting what the reference says!) this is different from *convergence*, which would typically be measured by a set of [trace plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120936/why-we-need-trace-plot-for-mcmc-results?rq=1) or a display of the [Gelman-Rubin statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255990/how-closely-related-are-the-gelman-rubin-statistic-and-the-autocorrelation-lengt).

Here's what the reference says about the plot:

> Following Primiceri (2005), we assess the convergence of the Markov chain by inspecting the autocorrelation properties of the ergodic distribution’s draws. Specifically, in what follows we consider the draws’ inefficiency factors (henceforth, IFs), defined as
>   the inverse of the relative numerical efficiency measure of Geweke (1992),
>   $$
> RNE = (2 \pi)^{-1} \frac{1}{S(0)} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} S(\omega) \, d\omega
> $$
>   where S(ω) is the spectral density of the sequence of draws from the Gibbs sampler
>   for the quantity of interest at the frequency ω. ...
>   Figure 10 shows the draws’ IFs for the models’ hyperparameters–i.e., the free
>   elements of the matrices $Q$, $Z$, and $S$ - and for the states, i.e. the time-varying coefficients of the VAR (the $\theta_t$), the volatilities (the $h_{i,t}$ ’s), and the non-zero elements of the matrix $A_t$. As the figure clearly shows, the autocorrelation of the draws is uniformly very low, being in the vast majority of cases around or below 3–as stressed by
>   Primiceri (2005, Appendix B), values of the IFs below or around twenty are generally
>   regarded as satisfactory.