# How closely related are the Gelman-Rubin statistic and the autocorrelation length?

Tags: simulation, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo

When monitoring the convergence of parallel MCMC chains, some people measure the autocorrelation length, others the Gelman-Rubin statistic.  (There are others who use some other statistic and still others who don't bother with any, but let's ignore that here.)  I have even been told to monitor both.  I'm wondering how closely these two statistics are related.

Here I'm defining the Gelman-Rubin statistic $\hat{R}$ in the sense of the [original paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/itsim.pdf) (some people use alternate definitions) and the autocorrelation length as $n_{cor} = \sum_{t=-\infty}^{\infty} [C(t)/C(0)]$ where $C(t)$ is the autocorrelation with lag $t$.  (Some people divide this by 2 to match an exponential 2-sided falloff, but I won't.)  Also I'm just tracking a single parameter for each quantity, no fancy multidimensional definitions here. $n$ is the number of steps in the MCMC run and $m$ the number of chains.

A heuristic argument suggests the Gelman-Rubin statistic $\hat{R}$ should be related to the autocorrelation length by
$$
   \hat{R}^2 - 1 \approx \frac{n_{cor}}{n}  \; .
$$
Measuring both $n_{cor}$ and $\hat{R}$ in a small set of Markov processes, I find this holds reasonably well with a bit of scatter, as shown in the plot below.  The chains used include an autoregressive process and MCMC samples from Gaussian posterior functions of different dimensions, with different proposal widths in some cases.  Colored lines connect different stages of the same runs.

[image]

But can the connection be made more explicit?  What is the more accurate statement here?

1. for slight tweaks in the definition, $\hat{R}$ is simply a function of $n_{cor} / n$ for *any* $n$
2. The expectation value of $\hat{R}$ is simply a function of that of $n_{cor} / n$ in the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$
3. $\hat{R}$ and $n_{cor} / n$ are only closely related for a small subset of posterior functions.

The convergence test I've seen people use with the autocorrelation length is $n > 10 n_{cor}$ or something like that, while the usual convergence test using the Gelman-Rubin statistic is $\hat{R} > 1.05$ or so.  These are equivalent according to the rule above.  I wonder if there are nevertheless many situations where one test fails where the other one passes.  (I can think of one.  If the posterior has two similar modes and the chains are all stuck inside one or the other, the run time can be large compared to the autocorrelation length while the Gelman-Rubin statistic will be quite large.)

(Addendum: I'm now not sure there's great value in any magic threshold of either $\hat{R}$ or $n / n_{cor}$.  Usually the real quantity of interest is how many independent states you have, because this determines how good your sampling is.  But this number is $n m / n_{cor}$, so it depends on $m$ as well.  Therefore if you want 500 samples and $m$ is 4, you might need $\hat{R} < 1.004$, whereas if $m$ is 200, you might need only $\hat{R} < 1.15$.)

Comment: Consider a case in which the posterior is multimodal, you run two chains and each of the chain converges to a different mode. Depending on your proposal distribution (assuming you are running a MH-algorithm) the autocorrelation length might be quite short. The G-R statistic, on the other hand, would be probably quite large. In short, I doubt that you can express the one as a function of the other.